# Java -Print String from arraylist

Tags: java

How do i print a string from an arraylist?

Comment: *FYI:* Your naming is reversed. Java naming convention is for class names to start with uppercase letter, and for variable names to start with lowercase letter, so `Person` and `people` would be normal way to name things.

Comment: You are saving the (shortest) height, but you are not saving the _Person_ who has that height. You want to remember the shortest person, then print the `toString()` of that person. See Andreas' answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the shortest person, so you can use other information from that person, you need to remember the person, not just the height of the person, like this:

```
person shortest = null;
for (person p : People) {
    if (shortest == null || p.getHeight() < shortest.getHeight()) {
        shortest = p;
    }
}

String s = shortest.toString();
```

You may of course need to check if `People` is empty, otherwise you'll get an `NullPointerException` when you try to call `toString()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use java 8 for this purpose:

```
Optional <Person> shortestPersonOpt = people.stream().min(Comparator.comparingDouble(Person::getHeight));
```

the result is optional as you may not always have the shortest person. To actually obtain and use the person you should do:

```
if(shortestPersonOpt.isPresent()){
   Person shortestPerson = shortestPersonOpt.get();
   //now you can use it
}
```

Comment: That is because the code is missing a piece, i.e. the `comparingDouble` part: `Optional<person> shortestPersonOpt = People.stream().min(Comparator.comparingDouble(person::getHeight));`

Comment: @Andreas Thank you for the edit! I just wrote it directly and forgot about the comparator.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the person, not the value of the height.

```
Person smallest = null;
for (Person person : People) {
  if (smallest == null || person.getHeight() < smallest.getHeight()) {
    smallest = person;
  }
}
```

// smallest is now null if no People in the list, or the Person with the smallest value.

Comment: Please explain your answer, and how it solves the question.